# Program entering an infinite loop

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I am new to programming so this might come off as a silly question but can you help me with this code..... I am trying to print just the first ten numbers after the number 'self.num' but somehow it is just entering an infinite loop which I am having to terminate

```
class TopTen:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):

        if self.num <= self.num+10:
            val= self.num
            self.num += 1

            return val
        else:
            raise StopIteration
values = TopTen(5)

for i in values:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `if self.num <= self.num+10:` do you not think it is always true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
class TopTen:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num
    self.maxNum = num+10

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def next(self):
    if self.num < self.maxNum:
      val = self.num
      self.num += 1
      return val
    else:
      raise StopIteration


for i in TopTen(5):
  print(i)

# Prints
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
# 11
# 12
# 13
# 14
```

The reason why you have infinite loop is because `if self.num <= self.num + 10:` will always evaluate to `True`, as you increase self.num by 1 each time by calling `next()`, so `self.num + 10` will always be higher than `self.num`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition test `if self.num <= self.num+10:` in your class will always be true, thats the reason for the infinite loop: